# Check two strings for matching characters that also have the same index (python)

Tags: python-3.x

**Challenge:** 
Write a program that uses 2 strings. For every character in *'string_1'*, check whether *'string_2'* has the same character at precisely the same index. Print character and index for every match.

Could someone provide a few pointers?

```
string_1 = "The Holy Grail"
string_2 = "Life of Brian"

for char in string_1:
    if char in string_2:
        <compare indices between string_1 and string_2, but how?>
    print(char + index)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you ensure that this is NOT from any live coding contests from the Internet?

Comment: Nope, from the python course I'm following

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to take the index of smaller string for iterating in for loop else it will throw "string index out of range" error

Here string_1 has 14 letters and string_2 has 13 letters. So I took the index of string_2 for use in my for loop

Please find below code that gives the output as required by you

```
string_1 = "The Holy Grail"
string_2 = "Life of Brian"

for i in range(len(string_2)):
    if string_1[i] == string_2[i]:
        print(i, string_1[i])
```

And the output is :

```
5 o
11 a
```

Let me know whether it helps. Thanks

Comment: Hi JKC, that was really helpful, thanks! I was kind of close at some point looking at your solution. Still just a beginner, with trouble 'seeing a solution', hope this will improve.

Comment: Glad it helped you. If you are satisfied with my response, you can accept it as the answer to this question.

Comment: @GJ01 if you feel it's not the solution as you expected, please let me know the reason and expected output from my code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
string_1 = "The Holy Grail"
string_2 = "Life of Brian"
zip_texts = zip(string_1 , string_2 )
enum_texts = list(enumerate(zip_texts))
for i, (a, b) in enum_texts:
    if a == b:
        print(f'index {i}: "{a}" = "{b}"')
```

Output :

index 5: "o" = "o" 
index 11: "a" = "a"